# ffmpg (copy existing settings?) or crop a .mov with alpha and have it be open-able using Quicktime (not VLC)

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, quicktime, alpha

How do you have ffmpeg copy all existing settings except the crop dimensions of a video file?

I've been struggling to crop an .mov with alpha channel (transparent video), so that it can be opened using Quicktime (instead of VLC). However, it seems that the output is either black background or somethig Quicktime cannot open. I've tried these variations and a number of others to no avail...

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "crop=1080:1080:420:0" -pix_fmt yuv420p output2.mov`

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "crop=1080:1080:420:0" -pix_fmt yuva420p output2.mov`

Comment: Paste the readout of `ffmpeg -i input.mov`

Comment: It does say this - but which other format can i choose that quicktime can open with alpha channel? `Incompatible pixel format 'yuva420p' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'`